# how to typeset the word same as the following picture?

Tags: fonts, symbols

[image]

How can I typeset the word as the above picture? All letters of the word are uppercase but the first is taller than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *small capitals* style:

```
\textsc{Sparsity}
```